# saving sql dump error in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-scripting

I want to save `error` if error comes, into a file. But error not redirecting into file.

### I get below error and its not redirecting into file.

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `v_comloc`': View 'nextgendev_new.v_comloc' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them (1356)
```

### My attempt

```
HOST="localhost"
PASS="aaaaa"
LOCAL_DIR="/userBackupDrive/backupDatabases/"           #Modified local directory
DAY="`date +%a`"
DATE="`date +%F`"
USER="root"

for db in `mysql -h $HOST -u $USER -p$PASS -e "show databases"`
     do
         mysqldump --opt --routines --single-transaction -p$PASS -u $USER -h $HOST --databases $db | gzip -9 > $LOCAL_DIR$db.$DAY.sql.gz  2>>/var/log/failedJobs/mysqlCronJob.log  

                RESULT=$?
                if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ] ; then
                        echo
                else
                        echo "$DATE__  $db backup not successful" >> /var/log/failedJobs/dbError.log

                fi
     done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were redirecting errors from `gzip`, not from `mysqldupmp`.

Put redirection before pipe, like this:

```bash
mysqldump --opt --routines --single-transaction -p$PASS -u $USER -h $HOST \
          --databases $db 2>>/var/log/failedJobs/mysqlCronJob.log \
         | gzip -9 > $LOCAL_DIR$db.$DAY.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to redirect standard output (">") twice, which doesn't work.

Perhaps you want this:

```
     mysqldump --opt --routines --single-transaction -p$PASS -u $USER -h $HOST --databases $db 2>/var/log/failedJobs/mysqlCronJob.log | gzip -9 > $LOCAL_DIR$db.$DAY.sql.gz
```

Comment: Thank you, it working for output redirect  as guided by you.   But why exit code giving `zero`  while there is error in db backup for few databases.    ?

Comment: That is probably the exit code of gzip, gzip has no problem. In stead of testing the exit code, you could test if mysqlCronJob.log is not empty.